# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'bdpruebas.a.fecha' isn't in GROUP BY

Tags: mysql

tengo esta consulta que si la ejecuto en el servidor mediante phpmyadmin me funciona y me devuelve los resultados correspondientes.

```
        $sqlTramo1 = 'SELECT
        format(100 - (avg(a.ultimo)*100/max(max)),2) as diferencia
         FROM calculos a
         left join valores b
         on a.valor_id = b.id
        where day(a.fecha) between 1 and 10 and year(a.fecha) = 2021 and a.valor_id = 5
        group by month(a.fecha),year(a.fecha),b.nombre,b.id
        order by b.nombre asc,  MONTH(a.fecha)  asc';
        
        
    $grafTramo1 = DB::select($sqlTramo1);
```

El problema lo tengo cuando intento ejecutarlo desde laravel como una query me da este error

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'bdpruebas.a.fecha' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: SELECT format(100 - ....
```

He probado a poner a.fecha en el gropu by pero claro...la query no devuelve lo que necesito entonces.

Gracias

Comment: Puedes poner el código de Laravel? Quizá el Eloquent está mal montado...

Comment: No tiro un eloquent tiro un DB::select, es la primera parte de código que muestro.